# Get count of custom post tags

Tags: tags, count

I am trying to get the count of custom post tags `gd_place_tags`. But I just get the value "0" back.

```
    function tag_count( $tagatts ) {

    $tagatts = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'gd_place_tags','hide_empty' => false));
    return ( isset( $tagatts->count ) ) ? $tagatts->count : 0; 
}
add_shortcode( 'tag_count', 'tag_count' );
```

And yes, I'm not a developer but I am trying to learn! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you try:

```
function tag_count( $tagatts ) {

  $tagatts = get_terms( 
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'gd_place_tags',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    )
  );

  $tagatts_count = count ( $tagatts );
  return $tagatts_count;
}
add_shortcode( 'tag_count', 'tag_count' );
```

it should actually return the term count.  I'm just using php for Count instead of a wordpress function.

Comment: Could be so easy thank you rudtek. its working fine.